# PHP Drop Down Menu To Retrieve Results

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I've put together the script below that displays a list of dates from a mySQL database.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host", "user", "password")or
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");
?>
<form>
<select>

<?php 
$result = "SELECT userdetails.userid, finds.dateoftrip, detectinglocations.locationname, finds.findid, finds.userid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid, finds.findname, finds.finddescription FROM userdetails, finds, detectinglocations WHERE finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND finds.userid = 1 GROUP By dateoftrip ORDER BY dateoftrip DESC";     
$result =mysql_query($result);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<option value ="<?php echo $data['findid'] ?>" ><?php echo $data['dateoftrip'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
</form>
```

What I'd now like to do is upon a date being selected, retrieve the associated values from the fields 'findname' and 'finddescription, inserting them in a table on my page.

I've spent hours trying to get this to work, without any success. I just wondered whether someone could perhaps give me a helping hand please and let me know what I need to do to retrieve the results.

Many thanks

**Updated Code**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host", "user", "password")or
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");
?>
<form>
<select>

<?php 
$result = "SELECT dateoftrip, findid, userid, locationid, findname, finddescription FROM finds GROUP By dateoftrip ORDER BY dateoftrip DESC";  

$result =mysql_query($result);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<option value ="<?php echo $data['findid'] ?>" ><?php echo $data['dateoftrip'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
</form>
```

Comment: no findid in your select query.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. You have this dropdown menu and, depending on what the user selects, you need to retrieve some data from your bd ?

Comment: Both, apologies, I've amended my post to be more accurate. Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let me know what I need to do to retrieve the results

what you need is:

1.**repair query**

```
SELECT 
   userdetails.userid AS userdetails_userid, 
   finds.dateoftrip, 
   detectinglocations.locationname, 
   finds.userid AS finds_userid, 
   finds.locationid AS finds_locationid , 
   detectinglocations.locationid AS detectinglocations_locationid ,
   finds.findname, 
   finds.finddescription 
FROM 
   userdetails, 
   finds, 
   detectinglocations 
WHERE 
   finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND 
   finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND 
   finds.userid = 1 
GROUP By 
   finds.dateoftrip
ORDER BY 
   finds.dateoftrip DESC
```

2.insert generating code into variable and then echo

```
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $options .="<option value =\"". $data['userdetails_userid'] ."\">". $data['finds_locationid'] ."</option>";
}
echo "<select>". $options ."</select>";
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. I've tidied the query up considerably and amended my original post to reflect this. I did however keep the form as it was, as your suggestion placed the values outside the drop down menu. Kind regards

Comment: ok :) your welcome. 1 more thing... dropdown menus works on users side and php on server.

Answer (score 1):

Your form needs a destination php file to submit to, and a submit button:

```
<form method="post" action="handle_submission.php">
...

<input type="submit" value="Search" name="search"/>
</form>
```

`handle_sumbission.php` will receive the form selection as entries in $_POST. I'd start with a separate script like this and once you get it working, you could fold them into one script if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an AJAX script that should do the job.

//JQuery library must be included

//Script for page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#findname").blur(function()
            {
             //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading
             $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
             //check the username exists or not from ajax
             $.post("user_availability.php",{ username:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
             {
              if(data=='no') //if username not avaiable
              {
               $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
               {
                //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                $(this).html('Username not available to register').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
               });
              }
              else
              {
               $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  //start fading the messagebox
               {
                //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                $(this).html('Username available to register').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1);
               });
              }
             });
            });
       });
    </script>
```

Put your PHP mySQL query in a script names user_availability.php and have the script actioned once the user leaves the field. The script is looking for a 'yes' or 'no' if mySQL finds a match but you could also have the PHP script return anything you want.

Here is an example of how the PHP script works:

```
// Connect to MYSQL database //
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'root';
    $db = 'table';  



    $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die ("Couldn't connect to mySQL!");
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connect);
    mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Couldn't find the database");

// Form value sent by AJAX
    $user_name=$_POST['username'];
    $length = strlen($user_name);
    if ($length < 5) {
      echo "no"; exit();
    }

// Grab all users in the database
$query = "SELECT username FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result); $i=0;

while ($i < $count) {
  $existing_user = mysql_result($result, $i, 'username');
     if ($user_name == $existing_user) 
     {
        exit();
     }
  $i++;   
}
//No matches so return OK to proceed with name 
echo "yes";
```

Answer (score 0):

As allready mentioned the drop down menu will be userside. If you want this to work with php only, you could send a GET value back to the page. Catch that value and do the query with it ...

The link in the dropdown list could be:

```
<a href="mypage.php?date=2012-03-08">datetodisplay</a>
```

You would catch it like:

```
$date = $_GET['date'];
```

Then You'd have to change you're query and add the $date into a WHERE clause like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM WHERE date = " . $date;
```

Don't know if I give what You need ... and of course You should check this GET value and real_escape it before using it in a query ...